# Is there a better way to do this than writing a wrapper allocator that stores a reference to a stateful allocator object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, lambda, allocator, std-function

For example:

```
struct Foo {
    MyPoolAlloc<char> pool;
    std::vector<int , MyPoolAlloc<char>> vec_int; // The wrapper allocator would replace MyPoolAlloc<> here.
    std::vector<std::function<void()> , MyPoolAlloc<char>> vec_funcs; // The wrapper allocator would replace MyPoolAlloc<> here.

    Foo() : vec_int(pool) , vec_funcs(pool) {}

    // I want to store lambdas with captured variables using the custom allocator as well:
    template<typename Func>
    void emplace_back(const Func& func) {
        vec_funcs.emplace_back(std::allocator_arg , pool , func);
    }
};
```

In the above code, I want ALL allocations (besides the pool itself) to pull from the same `pool` object. Is the best way to do this writing a wrapper allocator that stores a reference to an actual stateful allocator object? And then pass the following into the constructors (example):

```
: vec_int ((MyWrapperAlloc<char>(pool)));
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this than writing a whole extra wrapper class for `MyPoolAlloc<>`?

Comment: Do you literally mean that there's only one pool? (Then it's not stateful.)

Comment: Also, if you want those `function`s to respect the allocator, check out my library: https://github.com/potswa/cxx_function . Use it with `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter If a lambda captures a copy of `std::string`, it doesn't seem to use my allocator for the string contents. Does the scoped allocator fix that, or is that something your library does?

Comment: To move things into a new pool, the target object needs a "copy"-constructor with an allocator as the second parameter. Lambdas can't do this; you need to declare a class. [Here](https://github.com/potswa/cxx_function/blob/master/test/scoped_allocator.cpp#L52)'s an example, though it's only a testcase and not a tutorial :( . Also note, I just made some fixes so you might download a new copy of the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard "Allocator" concept would have been better named "AllocatorReference." Each object either refers to a global instance (stateless) or to an external object (stateful).

Either way, the allocator instance within an allocator-aware container does not own a memory pool by itself. It's only a proxy. Note that allocator objects are often copied as they are rebound and returned by value. You don't want `vector::get_allocator` to copy a whole memory pool.

So, yes, you need two classes.

1. The "wrapper," "proxy," or "reference" which satisfies the standard Allocator requirements and takes a template parameter for the allocated type.
2. The memory pool which has nothing to do with the Allocator interface but does know how to perform allocations.